# .Error in Streambuilder for flutter firestore note app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Error: 1.The argument type 'Stream' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.
2.The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'.
3.Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra arguments.
taskstream-

```
DatabaseServices().getTasks(uId).then((val){
    taskstream=val;
    });

Widget taskList(){

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: taskstream,//error 1
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return snapshot.hasData ?
        ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return TaskTile(
                snapshot.data!.docs[index].data["isCompleted"],//3 and 2
                snapshot.data!.docs[index].data["task"],//3
                snapshot.data!.docs[index].documentID,
              );
            }) : Container();
      },
    );
```

database gettask function-

```
getTasks(String userId) async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users")
        .doc(userId)
        .collection("tasks")
        .snapshots();
  }

class TaskTile
class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isCompleted;
  final String task;
  final String documentId;
  TaskTile(this.isCompleted, this.task, this.documentId);

  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}
```

Comment: what version of firestore are you using and what is taskStream equal to?

Comment: Also if you share your `taskstream` it'd be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to where you defined `taskstream`, and define it as `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`. Then in your Widget, do the following:

```
Widget taskList(){

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: taskstream,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return snapshot.hasData ?
        ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return TaskTile(
                snapshot.data!.docs[index].data.get("isCompleted"),
                snapshot.data!.docs[index].data.get("task"),
                snapshot.data!.docs[index].documentID,
              );
            }) : Container();
      },
    );
```

Comment: Thank you Sir ! The errors are gone as u said but now I am getting a late initialization error:Field 'taskstream' has not been initialized at run time..I would be very grateful if you could tell a way out looking at the code in the question...For your reference the taskstream has been written like-late Stream <QuerySnapshot> taskstream; before assigning the value

Comment: You're most welcome, please share the code for the stream. But you can remove late and write your code like collection.doc.snapshots